# SMS ad service for a PHP app

Tags: advertising, sms

I am about to launch a website that allows the end user to get alerted as their bus approches the stop. The only problem was this is a little expensive as I'm paying about 5 cents per alert. I was thinking that if I added a short message something like "brought to you by acme co" at the end of the message I may be able to recoup cost without making my service a paid one.

Anyone know of any SMS ad companies or how one would go about finding one. Google has failed me, probably searching for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Twilio costs $0.01 per message](http://www.twilio.com/pricing-signup/) (Non-US is in [private beta](http://www.twilio.com/international-sms)).

As for adverts, I just googled [SMS adverts](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sms+adverts) and got a load of companies that sell advertising. Maybe get in touch with a few of them and ask them.

Comment: I'm using twilio but it's 2 cents in and two cents out. Which makes 4 cents. I found a lot of companies that were SELLING SMS ads but I was having trouble finding one that would let me profit from ads.

Answer (score 1):

The only non-sketchy SMS ad network I know of is [4INFO](http://mobilemedia.4info.com/publishers/). They also have a program called AdHaven Mobile, but I'm not sure how it's different from their ad service for publishers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer's late by a few months, but just in case you're still looking or someone else finds this question...

Check out [Inuvi](http://inuvi.com) and please contact us if it looks like we can help.

Here are some ways in which Inuvi differs from 4INFO:

- We provide publishers (and mobile
  operators) with an ad service only.
- We don't offer the full SMS
  publishing, delivery, and advertising
  solution that 4INFO provides.
- We operate globally.
- We
  have a low minimum spend for
  advertisers.
- We don't charge a set-up
  or service fee to publishers and mobile operators.

By the way, if anyone's interested, here's the [Inuvi blog](http://blog.inuvi.com).